# Tapestry Load Image Asset from Filesystem

Tags: image, filesystems, assets, tapestry

i'm using Tapestry 5.3 and jetty 9. I want to display image from filesystem (ex:"/opt/images/") is it possible to create asset from external folder in filesystem? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks before ~

Answer (score 0):

You can return a [StreamResponse](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/StreamResponse.html) from an event handler

Java

```
@Inject
private ComponentResources resources;

public StreamResponse onExternalImage(final String someArg) {
    return new StreamResponse() {
        public String getContentType() {
           return "image/jpeg";
        }
        public InputStream  getStream() {
           // todo implement
           // be very careful you don't allow a hacker to
           // access your entire file system using ../../ etc
        }
        public void prepareResponse(Response response) { }
    };
}

public Link getExternalImageLink(String someArg) {
    return resources.createEventLink("externalImage", someArg);
}
```

TML

```
<img src="${getExternalImageLink('foo')}" />
<img src="${getExternalImageLink('bar')}" />
```

Note that using the local file system is usually a bad idea. If the file is static, it's best to source from the classpath. If the file is not static you should consider storing in a database / blobstore.

Accessing the local file system raises many issues including transactions, concurrency and security and should normally be avoided

Comment: Thanks for your answer Lance ! Yeah, accessing local file is a bad idea, but i have no idea too to use blob type. I'm using Postgres and some people said Postgres blob is different from mysql blob.

Comment: It's very simple, @see [PreparedStatement.setBlob(column, InputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBlob(int,%20java.io.InputStream)) and [ResultSet.getBinaryStream(column)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBinaryStream(java.lang.String)) and [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BinaryFilesInDB)

Comment: Yes, i have read that link and got some bright light to fix this issue :D